# Is there a way to override what shortcut gets pinned to Windows taskbar?

Tags: javafx, windows-10

I have a JavaFX application that consists of a `Launcher.exe` and an `App.exe`.  When the application is installed on client machines, a shortcut to `Launcher` is created on their desktop.

This shortcut performs some actions and then runs `App.exe`, which cannot be run directly and must be called from `Launcher`.

The issue my users are having is they are trying to "pin" this application to their Windows 10 taskbars by right-clicking on the taskbar button for `App.exe` and pinning that.

Is there a way to override that behavior so that it actually pins the shortcut for `Launcher.exe` instead?

Comment: Which tool do you use to wrap the jars into .exe and which tool for the installer ?

Comment: I'm using whatever IntelliJ uses for its packaging and Paquet Builder for the installation.